# Create tetrahedron with each individual shape linking to page

Tags: javascript, html, svg, gallery, css-shapes

[Tetrahedron Menu Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cQ6H.jpg)

[[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cQ6H.jpg]]

Please see the attached image, I'm having a hard time creating a responsive group of triangles that form a tetrahedron. Each individual triangle I want to link to a page. The middle triangle will just be an image. Any help is greatly appreciated, I've been looking everywhere and can't find any examples of this.

Comment: here's an example, can't get the triangles closer together, and having issues with the roll overs, and the bottom triangle. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MppzaK

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by having divs over the image and place them using `position:absolute`.

Here is a pen of what I did (did it for the first triangle) : [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OppaxY)

```css
.myImg{
  width:500px;
  height:400px;
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cQ6H.jpg')
}

.triangle-left {
  position:absolute;
  top:40px;
  left:60px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 96px solid transparent;
  border-right: 98px solid transparent;
  border-top: 170px solid transparent;
  opacity:0.5;
  cursor:pointer;
  z-index:20;
}

.triangle-left:hover {
  border-top: 170px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class='myImg'></div>
<div class='areas'>
  <div class='triangle-left'></div>
  <div class='triangle-right'></div>
  <div class='triangle-bottom'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, works great. However, would I be able to have a hover effect on the middle triangle? As well, is there any way of doing this responsively? Sorry about the odd request, I'm not familiar with creating obscure menus like this.

Comment: I don't understand what your trying to do. Do you need to have a hover effet over an image or just over the shape ?

Comment: If you just need to hover over elements rather than images you can just do something like this : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wJJbjx

Comment: Thanks for your help! I ended up creating SVG's. Way easier.